# I am trying to execute spring jdbc program,but at the time running the application getting exceptions

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to execute spring jdbc program,but at the time running the application getting exceptions like

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.core.convert.converter.ConverterRegistry.addConverter(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter;)V"

How to resolve this issue? I added below jar.
spring-core-3.1.0.RELEASE
spring-core-3.0.3.RELEASE
spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE
spring.beans-3.1.1

Comment: spring-core-3.1.0.RELEASE spring-core-3.0.3.RELEASE spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE spring.beans-3.1.1 jar mismatch issue . keep everything to 4.1.6.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that all your spring dependencies are the same version. In your case, you are mixing core 3.1.0 and 3.0.3 with context 4.1.6 and beans 3.1.1. Keep them consistent. If you want to use the highest version in your dependencies then make all of them 4.1.6.RELEASE.

Perhaps you should also consider using spring-io-platform to get a managed set of dependencies with versions that will not conflict. This can be found at http://platform.spring.io/platform/